# How to shorten repetitive div elements in XPath selection?

Tags: html, xml, web-scraping, xpath, automation

Is there any nicer way to write this ? Right now it's 16 `div`s nested in each other and it works. But I'm afraid, what if in some unknown situation it could be different numbers of `div`s and my selection doesn't work?

```
//div[@data-pagelet="root"]/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/h2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This XPath,

```
//div[@data-pagelet="root"]//h2
```

will select all `h2` element descendants of `div` elements with `@data-pagelet` attribute values of `"root"`, regardless of heritage.